# How to translate the view using transform of Animated.View in React Native without remaining the blank space where it was

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here I have translated the `<MyComponent>` towards the upper direction by 100. But here, the blank space below `<MyComponent>` is still there, though the component is translated towards upper side.

```
<Animated.View
   style={{
      transform: [
           {
               translateY: -100,
           }]
         }}>
        <View>
            <MyComponent/>
        </View>
</Animated.View>
```

[image]

1. Before traslation
2. what it happens now
3. what I want to do

I want to translate the component removing the space where the component was. Please note that in my case the container with both boxes can not be translated.

Comment: Can you provide clearer details about what you mean by "blank space below ... is still there"? As written it is very unclear what the issue is.

Comment: You'll need to translate all the elements individually, or translate the container containing them all.

Comment: I just updated with an image. Please have a visit now. Thank you Drew Reese.

Comment: Yes. But this is not the real case. This image is only for illustratation. In my case, I can't move the container. Both boxes should be translated individually.